# How can I update UI using loops in Javascript based on user input & timer?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops, callback

Sounds complicated, but bear with me. I want to make a simple game in PHP/JS/Jquery. The data is being retrieved from the database in JSON. It is an array of questions, hints, answers & the correct answer.

I want to present all the questions on a single php page, one by one. The user can click any button, when he/she clicks the right answer, a green checkmark is shown & the score is updated. The next question is shown and so on. If the user runs out of time before attempting all 4 buttons, a red cross is shown, the score stays the same. The next question is shown.

Now, I can loop through the questions, but I cannot wait on user input, since JS is async, so I have to add callbacks. I can't think of a way to code it up in a way that makes verification easy without compromising the correct answer.

Here is some barebones code that gets the data from the db, and uses regular loops, no callbacks. How do I tweak this to get it to do what I want?

```
// Global variables
var QNAData = null;
var currentQuestionIndex = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Get question & answer data from the db
    function reqListener () {

        QNAData = jQuery.parseJSON(this.responseText);
        StartGame(QNAData);
    }

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
    oReq.open("GET", "GetNewGameData.php", true);
    oReq.send();

}); // end document.ready


function StartGame(QNAData)
{

            // Loop through the questions
           for (stageIndex=0; stageIndex < QNAData.length; stageIndex++) {

               currentQuestionIndex = stageIndex;
               // Populate the Question and Answer text containers
               $("#QuestionTextContainer").html(QNAData[stageIndex]['QuestionText']);
               $('#QuestionShortHintContainer').text(QNAData[stageIndex]['QuestionHintShort']);
               $('#QuestionLongHintContainer').text(QNAData[stageIndex]['QuestionHintLong']);
               $("#Answer1TextContainer").html(QNAData[stageIndex]['AllAnswersText'][0]);
               $("#Answer2TextContainer").html(QNAData[stageIndex]['AllAnswersText'][1]);
               $("#Answer3TextContainer").html(QNAData[stageIndex]['AllAnswersText'][2]);
               $("#Answer4TextContainer").html(QNAData[stageIndex]['AllAnswersText'][3]);


     // Set up the countdown timer after the answers have been displayed
     $('#countdown-container').hide().fadeIn().ClassyCountdown();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using only one question and changing text and answers is very troublesome. I would recommend building HTML for all questions, and only show the current one (control via JS). Your life will be much easier having to just control visibility and not constantly updating text and values around. This will also help you in not changing values and text while user is clicking on answer, since the HTML is different.

Second, there's no way around callbacks in JS. Accept it. You'll need click handlers, change handlers, timeout handlers, ajax handler, all callbacks.

As for the user timeout problem, here's how I'd do it:

You want to use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). On the function for its callback, make it the function that displays the timeout cross.

The return value of it is a handler, which you can store in a variable.
In case the user press button to check answer for example, or to move to other questions, you can use [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) and pass the stored timeout, so it won't run.
Then create a new one for the new question being displayed.